# create dynamic URLs

Tags: php, url

i'm about to launch an advertisement campaign to promote my website,  the thing is i want to create landing pages with different urls to make it easy for me to track visitors and know what campaign works the best,  I've seen link like http://www.mywebsite.com/?id=1 and http://www.mywebsite.com/?id=2, both links show the main site content as well but with different URLS to make it easy to track visitors,  i wonder how to create such URLS, i hope you could help me, thanks.

Comment: Have you done some work? Would help if you elaborated on your research and efforts.

Comment: Example you have given is same URL but with different query string values for the ID variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `index.php` (or whatever PHP script is executed when going to `http://www.mywebsite.com/`) add code similar to this:

```
if(!empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    track_visit($id);
    header('Location: /');
    exit;
}
```

The function `track_visit()` can be as simple as logging a visit for the given ID or more complicated and e.g. check if the user's IP was already tracked recently.

The redirect after tracking is used so the id argument doesn't stay in the URL - otherwise hitting refresh would track the user again if you used the most simple way of implementing `track_visit`. Besides that, keeping tracking information in the URL makes it look ugly (just look at the incredibly long `utm_campaign=...` etc. data you often have in the url when following a rss feed or newsletter link) and users copying the link to someone else would cause them to be tracked to - which might not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Besides that you schould really work on your basic knowledge about everything related to dynamic websites, you may just go with Google Analytics to track these campaigns, because it will give you much more information on each visitor …

[Google Analytics - How does campaign tracking work?](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55540)

If you don't want to go with a Google product I suggest you to take a look at Piwik instead

[Tracking Campaigns – Analytics Piwik](http://piwik.org/docs/tracking-campaigns/)